# Can't retrieve event store calendars?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ekeventstore

I have the iCloud calendars and some subscribed calendars on my device, all calendars apps including the native calendar app display the calendars correctly, but in my app i can't retrieve them.
I am trying to retrieve the event store calendars as follow:

A)

```
 NSArray *calendarArray = [self.eventStore calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];
// always return result an empty array
```

B)

```
 NSMutableArray *calendars = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 for (EKSource *source in self.eventStore.sources) {
        NSSet *sourceCalendars = [source calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];
        [calendars addObjectsFromArray:sourceCalendars.allObjects];
  }
// always return result an empty array
```

The event store instance is allocated and initialized correctly, and the privacy for accessing calendars also granted.

What can I do ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have more than 100 calendar and Reminder lists then event store stop working properly.

For more info check this link: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4489?viewlocale=en_US

Comment: I have more than 130 calendars for testing purpose, Thank u @ayman :)